# Laço de repetição com problema

Tags: python, array, índices

Tenho o algoritmo abaixo, e na linha `while lista[i]==lista[i-1]:` esta retornando o erro:

> index out of range

```
import random
n1=0
n2=0
n1=int(input('Insira um numero para inicio'))
n2=int(input('Insira um numero para limite'))
i=1
lista=[]
for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]:
    lista.append(random.randint(n1,n2))
i=1
count=0
print(lista[i-1])
lista.sort()
while i<=15:
    while lista[i]==lista[i-1]: 
        lista.pop(i)
        lista.insert(i,random.randint(n1,n2))
    i+=1
print(lista)
```

Comment: Geralmente quando você inicia um loop, a variável crescente sempre começa em 0, no trecho `lista[i-1]` você está fazendo `0 - 1`, sendo assim o resultado é `-1` então ele não encontra o `index` da array, o que você pretende fazer nesse código?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 4):

O erro está em `while i<=15` que deveria ser `while i < 15`. A lista de 15 elementos vai de 0 a 14, então você tem que parar antes de chegar no 15, você está indo até o 15 com o o operador de "menor ou igual", não pode ser igual, então quando chega nele pega um elemento que não existe, o 15, e dá o erro.

Este código tem alguns problemas que não impedem a execução, e até parece que faz algumas coisas sem sentido. E ele poderia ser mais idiomático em Python, mas talvez se tirar tudo o que não faz sentido nem seja o caso.

Comment: Esse ponto aqui também é relevante para o problema!

Answer (score 2):

A resposta de Maniero é a mais correta. Basta trocar por `while i < 15:` que não terá mais esse erro.

Acho interessante você colocar uma condição para que n1 seja menor que n2, pois se n1 == n2, seu código não vai dar nenhum erro, mas vai entrar em um loop infinito, já que randint vai retornar sempre o mesmo número.